# Sort with single parameter in Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Programming and Practices 2nd edition

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm reading Bjarne Stroustrup new C++ PP 2nd edition and in it he uses a sort method as sort(someVector). I'm getting the following errors, when compiling code with this method.

> 3 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list
> argument types are: (Vector)    > c:\Microsoft_Press\C++\Debug\Temperature\Temperature\Temperature.cpp  19  2   Temperature

> Error 1   error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' : expects 3 arguments - 1 provided c:\microsoft_press\c++\debug\temperature\temperature\temperature.cpp    19  1   Temperature

> Error 2   error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided c:\microsoft_press\c++\debug\temperature\temperature\temperature.cpp    19  1   Temperature

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() 
{ 
    vector<double> temps; 
    for(double temp; cin>>temp;) 
    { 
        temps.push_back(temp); 
    } 
    double sum = 0; 
    for(double x : temps) 
    {   
        sum+= x; 
    } 
    cout<<"Average temperature: "<<sum/temps.size()<<"\n"; 
    sort(temps); 
    cout<<"Median temperature: "<<temps[temps.size()/2]<<"\n";
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Also please post the code. The error messages alone are not very informative.

Comment: code removed from comments

Comment: @d_blk do not post code in comments, rather edit the post to include the code

Comment: I'm a novice how can I use C++14 library with either VS2010,VS2012 or Xcode command line tools?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628936 although the appropriate library appears to be included here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-parameter sort is not yet available in C++. It will be enabled by concepts, but that was postponed from C++14 as well.

For now, you have to write:

```
std::sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

sort() expects the beginning and end of the range on which it is supposed to work. For example, `sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());`

The `temps.begin()` and `temps.end()` are correspondingly the begin and end iterator that define that range.