# Why doesn't the compiler recognize sort with a single argument?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am learning C++ from Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice with C++. I copied the code and the compiler found an error (E0304) with the usage of `sort(words)`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }

int main() {
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; )
        words.push_back(temp);
    cout << " Word count : " << words.size() << ' \n ';
    sort(words);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i])
            cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

Is this an error in the book, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that book comes with its own header file.

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), it should be `sort(words.begin(), words.end());`

Comment: *"an error (E0304)"* -- error codes are largely meaningless to most people. Please include the full error message, copied as text and pasted into your question.

Comment: @cigien The linked question probably isn't a (good) duplicate. See the discussion under my answer.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, I think you're right, the code in that question does include the necessary library, so it's likely an intellisense issue. Also, even if they're duplicates, this one has better answers on the whole, so this one should be used as a target anyway. Reopened now, thanks for the ping.

Answer (score 4):

The book explains at the beginning that you are supposed to include a file named `std_lib_facilities.h` coming with the book. It can also be downloaded from the author's website [here](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming_support.html).

This is a non-standard file used in the book to simplify some constructs for introducing the language.

This file defines a function `sort` that can be called directly on a container. The `std::sort` function from the standard library does not allow for that.

So add

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
```

at the beginning. (And I think you are also not supposed to add any of the standard library headers and `using namespace std;` yourself either. I can't check the book right now though.)

Comment: Your answer is worth adding to the duplicated question, that does not have a proper answer.

Comment: @273K In the linked question the header seems to be included correctly, which actually makes me think that it isn't really a duplicate. I can't really tell, but in the other question the error message seems to come from IntelliSense, not the compiler?

Comment: Ok. I have not noticed it. Yes, IntelliSense looks wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly looks wrong in IntelliSense?

Comment: @rodveyz I was talking about the linked duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070520/sort-with-single-parameter-in-bjarne-stroustrups-c-programming-and-practices. What the user there is asking seems to not be a compiler error, but just a warning from IntelliSense. So it is a distinct problem from the one you are asking about. The user in that question probably just has his IDE misconfigured (or at least that is my guess).

Answer (score 3):

Until C++20 the standard library didn't provide such a function. You can use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) like this:

```
std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
```

However, since this can be annoying, C++20 provides  [`std::ranges::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort), that does what you want:

```
std::ranges::sort(words);
```

To use this function you have to use a compiler that supports C++20.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` arguments are have to be iterators. Replace

```c
sort(words);
```

by

```c
sort(words.begin(), words.end());
```